# How do I access variables under liquid filter argument?

Tags: ruby, liquid

```
module MyFilter
  def all_caps(input)
    input.upcase
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(MyFilter)

template = Liquid::Template.parse(" {{ 'hi john' | all_caps }} ")
template.render 
# => " HI JOHN "

template = Liquid::Template.parse(" {{ 'hi {{name}}' | all_caps }} ")
template.render('name' => 'john') 
# => " ' | all_caps }} "
```

How do I fix this? No mentions in the official documentation.

Note: I have used all_caps example just for the simplicity. I want to achieve something complex.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out a way to do that. Would appreciate if there is any other solution.

```
template = Liquid::Template.parse("{% capture some_text %} Hi, {{name}} {% endcapture %} {{ some_text | all_caps }}")
template.render('name' => 'john')
```

Hope this helps.